# What does the plus and minus mean on the Argosy trade screen?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

When trading with the Argosy, I noticed that some of the trade goods and some of my commodities had either a plus sign with a blue highlight on the cost bar or a minus sign with a purple bar. I figured that this meant that the value of the commodity/trade good was increased or decreased, but I couldn't tell which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plus and minus mean the opposite things, depending on whether or not you're looking at your commodities, or the Argosy items you want to trade for.

On your commodities, the <kbd>+</kbd> means it's worth more than usual to the Argosy trader, and <kbd>-</kbd> means it's worth less.

When viewing the Argosy trade items, a <kbd>+</kbd> means that the trader wants *less* for the item than he usually wants for it, and a <kbd>-</kbd> means he wants more.

To generalize it, <kbd>+</kbd> is good for you, and <kbd>-</kbd> is bad, no matter which screen you're looking at.

To my knowledge, there's no way to influence which items gain a <kbd>+</kbd> or a <kbd>-</kbd>.  It's completely random, and changes every time the Argosy shows up.